# How to reference containing anchor tag in it's href attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, bootstrap-4

I'm using reactjs with bootstrap. I want to show and collapse an unordered list within a list item (nested unordered list). Bootstrap has a collapse feature. If using an anchor tag, you can use a data-toggle attribute with a value of 'collapse' and you can reference the section you want shown or hidden within it's href attribute. Bootstrap documentation example below.

I want to reference the containing anchor element within it's href attribute.The function subList within the anchor tag returns an unordered list based on a passed in array. So the next tag or sibling to the anchor tag will be a ul tag and this is what I want to show and hide.

Thought the code below would do it but it tells me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined". So reference to "this" doesn't seem to be allowed here. Do I have a typo that I can't see for some reason or do I have the completely wrong approach and what I am doing can never be done this way?

I've researched google, stack overflow and bootstrap documentation, but there doesn't seem to be an example like this and it's hard to word the search terms correctly so that I might find an answer if it's out there.

Bootstrap documentation example

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
</a>
```

My code:

```
    const subList = (listArray) => {
        const output = [];
        for (const item of listArray) {
            output.push(<li>{item}</li>);
        }   
        return (<ul>{output}</ul>);
    };

    for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(props.card)) {
        if(Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 1) {
            cardJsx.push(<li><strong>{prop}: </strong><a data-toggle="collapse" href={this.nextSibling}>more</a>{subList(value)}</li>);
        }
        else{
            cardJsx.push(<li key={prop}><strong>{prop}:</strong> {value}</li>);
        }
    }
    return <div><ul>{cardJsx}</ul></div>;
```

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined"

Comment: There is no nesting of anchor tags. I want to reference one anchor tag within it's href **attribute**. I don't know where you see nested anchor tags and I showed the real html. This is react

Answer (score 0):

Try using value.length >= 1 in your if statement.

Comment: I am making a nested list in this case where each member of an object gets checked to see if it's value is an array instead of a string. If array, create a sub unordered list within parent unordered list. If the array only has one string value, might as well just take that string as the property value rather than created a sublist